# Support for async/await in Meteor tests

Tags: meteor

I can't seem to be able to test a meteor method when it's written using async/await.

`server/methods.js`

```js
Meteor.methods({
    async f() {
        const result = await new Promise((resolve) => 
              setTimeout(() => resolve("i'm done"), 500));
        return result;
    }
})
```

`server/methods.test.js`

```js
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import "./methods";

describe("f", () => {
     it("should return _i'm done_", done => {
          Meteor.call("f", (err, res) => {
              // MY PROBLEM: res equals {}
              done(err);
          });
     });
});
```

There is nothing special about my setup. This is the command I use to start my tests, meteor version is 1.4.2
`meteor test --driver-package dispatch:mocha`

Comment: I don't know how `Meteor.call` works, but async/await functions return promises, and I don't see any sort of `then` in your test.

Comment: good point. I've tried Meteor.call("f").then too, ended ended up with `can't call .then of undefined`